# Odd date formatting error when inserting records into MySQL database from CSV files

Tags: mysql, postgresql, datetime, csv

I am having this rather peculiar issue when dealing with records containing dates.

I am trying to read records from `.csv` files using a ruby script and inserting them into a mysql database.

The problem is that for some csv files, the date get inserted in the wrong format, I get dates like `0014/12/31`. I have tried my best to isolate the error but no luck. The other csv files get inserted just fine using the exact same code and have records with dates written in the exact same format as "31/7/2014" and get saved in my mysql db properly.

Here is the strange part, I opened the CSV files which are giving me errors to confirm their content using my default editor I had been using, MS Excel, clicked on the date column to check the format the dates were written in, didnt change anything and saved the file and exited excel, ran the script again and this time it worked perfectly.

I thought perhaps I had altered the file accidentally by opening and saving it again, so I took a screenshot of another csv file opened in another plain text editor (atom) and redid the same steps, opening in Excel, saving it and running the script again and the dates were being saved perfectly again.

I opened the file in atom again and took another screenshot for you guys, it's identical to the before picture. whats going on?!

- before : http://gyazo.com/6e431ed5c7011edf7fdac580de550019
- after : http://gyazo.com/91758b3866b5839161b9f142d39fa877

Ruby code parsing the dates :

```
def parse_to_date(param)

  Date.strptime(param,"%d/%m/%Y")
end


puts "REVENUE YTD--------------------------------------------"

CSV.foreach('X_Revenue_YTD.csv') do |row|

  next if row[0] == "Description" || row[0] == "Date" || row[0] == nil

  revenue_ytd_date = parse_to_date(row[0])
  actual_ci_amount = parse_to_int(row[1])
  budget_ci_amount = parse_to_int(row[2])
  actual_ad_amount = parse_to_int(row[3])
  budget_ad_amount = parse_to_int(row[4])
  actual_total_amount = parse_to_int(row[5])
  budget_total_amount = parse_to_int(row[6])
  actual_YTD_ci = parse_to_int(row[7])
  budget_YTD_ci = parse_to_int(row[8])
  actual_YTD_ad = parse_to_int(row[9])
  budget_YTD_ad = parse_to_int(row[10])
  actual_YTD_total = parse_to_int(row[11])
  budget_YTD_total = parse_to_int(row[12])

  insert_statement = <<-eos
    insert into dashboard_finance_revenue_ytd(
      sample_date, revenue_ytd_date, actual_ci_amount, budget_ci_amount,
      actual_ad_amount, budget_ad_amount, actual_total_amount,
      budget_total_amount, actual_YTD_ci, budget_YTD_ci, actual_YTD_ad,
       budget_YTD_ad, actual_YTD_total, budget_YTD_total
    ) values (
      '#{ SAMPLE_DATE }','#{ revenue_ytd_date }', '#{ actual_ci_amount }',
      '#{ budget_ci_amount }', '#{ actual_ad_amount }', '#{ budget_ad_amount     }',
      '#{ actual_total_amount }', '#{ budget_total_amount }', '#{     actual_YTD_ci }',
      '#{ budget_YTD_ci }', '#{ actual_YTD_ad }', '#{ budget_YTD_ad }',
      '#{ actual_YTD_total }', '#{ budget_YTD_total }'
    );
  eos
  conn.exec(insert_statement)
end
```

Comment: Eh?  Those two screen shots are not the same; one has a 2-digit year; the other has a 4-digit year.  You code says "Y", so it is expecting a full year -- not "14", which becomes 0014.

Comment: oh i must have missed that, my eyes getting tired !
 I guess the csv file must have some records in 4 digit and some in 2 digits, when i opened them with excel it must have change the 2 digit ones to the 4 digit format.
thanks !